# Как настроить локальный сервер с Ubuntu на MacOSX VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

Хочу работать с привычным сервером и ос локально. При всем том хочу открывать локальный сайт из браузера в macOS который отдавался бы сервером (Ubuntu) бегущим на виртуальный машине VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

На [rus-linux](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/vm/VirtualBox-networking.html), если я правильно понял проблему, есть подробное описание настройки локального хоста на virtualbox. Надеюсь поможет.